# Why are the jump codes I wrote not working with Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started coding in c #. I'm experimenting with Unity3d. I fixed the errors in my codes and I no longer get any errors, but the codes I wrote to jump my character do not work and my character does not jump. Can anyone help me ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController controller;
    Vector3 velocity;
    Rigidbody rb;
    bool isGrounded;
    public Transform ground;
    public float distance = 0.3f;
    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    public float jumpHeight;
    public float gravity;
    public LayerMask mask;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    }    
    private void Update()
    {
        #region Movement
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * horizontal + transform.forward * vertical;
        controller.Move(move*speed * Time.deltaTime);
        #endregion

        #region Jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravity);
        }
        #endregion       

        #region Gravity
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(ground.position, distance,mask);
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y <0)
        {
            velocity.y = 0f;
        }
        velocity.y += gravity + Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        #endregion
    }
}~~~
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the [help] to see how to use this site. First, don’t post code as images. It’s text and should be included as such, and formatted with the code button. Same goes with errors. Please edit the question and include the necessary information in it

Comment: Thank you for your warning...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a typo. In line 47 it should probably be

```
rb.velocity = Vector3.up*Time.deltaTime*jump;
```

There is an extra dot after deltaTime.

Comment: yes i realized when you said thank you very much

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Answer (score 0):

When posting code, please do so by copy-pasting it as text, not screen shots.
From what I see there, it seems that you're missing the declaration of `rb`, there should be a line like `Rigidbody rb;` at the top. Also note that you've moved the `OnTriggerStay` method inside of `Update`, so it will not be called by Unity as you'd probably expect. Move it outside of `Update` for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your warning in the first sentence. It is considered to have partially solved the problem. I rewrote the codes differently and got no errors but now my character is not jumping xD